# How to install tkinter in .local

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, pycharm, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 17.3 «Rosa»

I have 3 version of Python. In 2 different folder.

2.7.6 in /user/bin/Python2.7

3.4.3 in /user/bin/Python3.4

3.5.1 in /user/local/bin/Python3.5

I want to use TKinter with Python 3.5.1

For that i do in the terminal : $ sudo apt-get install python3-tk

The installation process work well. But the terminal told me this :

python3-tk (3.4.3-1~14.04.2) ...

and when i do this : $ python3

i got this : Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec 26 2015, 13:30:19)

3.4.3 and 3.5.1 are not equal and when i try to import tkinter in python console : i got a error message in the python console.

My question is what can i do to install TKinter for Python 3.5.1?

Thank's

Comment: How did you install Python 3.5.1 itself?

Comment: isn't tkinter installed automatycally with Python ? what message you get ?

Comment: on Mint 17.0 I use Felix Krull repo and I have `python3.5-tk` - see: http://askubuntu.com/a/682875/177036

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the python 3.5.1 was installed manually instead of from the package manager. Assuming that the tkinter installation for 3.4.3 will work for 3.5.1, all you need to do is to get tkinter onto the path for 3.5.1.

There are a couple of ways to do this depending on your end goal

inside of the python interpreter run

```
import sys
sys.path
```

This will show you the differences in your path. If you only want the tkinter lib. Add a symbolic link from the 3.4 lib to the 3.5 lib.

```
ln -s /path/to/tkinter/in/3.4 /path/to/a/dir/on/3.5s/path
```

You will probably need to run the above command as sudo.

Comment: I gonna try this also. Thank you, :)